# Show that an answer has been deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

When viewing a question, there's a little header that shows up when an answer or the question itself has been edited, saying "an edit has been made to this post; click to load". However, there's no such header when an answer is deleted, which to me seems to be a more significant action than an edit. Could something like the edit notification show up when the post is deleted? Or even something more obvious, perhaps.

Comment: Once you reach 10K then you will get the privilege to see deleted posts.  You gotta work for it!

Comment: @bluefeet My issue is actually more of the opposite of that. I'm still seeing the post on the page even after it's gone, with no indication that it's been deleted, until I refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure what the functional purpose of this would be besides UI consistency. "This answer has been deleted" isn't particularly useful.

Comment: I suppose my reason for raising this is mostly based on wanting things to be consistent. It seems wrong to me that you should be notified in real time of an edit, but not be told that the whole post is gone (which is, itself, a sort of massive edit)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Blast, didn't notice that

Comment: Delete is very different than edit. It's also much less common. As for the dupe no worry, happens to the best!